# Should I move my sick fish to a clean tank for treatment?

Tags: fish, aquarium, infections

My fish (all three) have ick, they currently live in a 33g tank. The fish are two platys and 1 catfish (he's small). I have a spare 10g tank that only has gravel and water in it.

It would be easier to medicate in that tank and keep it clean (I don't have to change as much water volume wise, etc). So I was wondering if it's wise to move them? Or would the stress do them more harm than good? I also cannot use full doses in the current tank because there are snails and I don't want to kill them accidentally.

Comment: IMO I'd move them so they get a full dose without risking the snails, but I don't have first hand experience with sick fish. [This answer](http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/6274/7988) to a related question has a lot more info!

Comment: And how about moving the snails to the other tank? What kind of snails are it? Normally they don't suffer that much from tank changes (differences in water parameters) or stress as fish. Once the treatment is over, you can then filter over carbon a couple days to remove any left over medicines.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use medications for FW ich. This is basically a myth perpetuated by companies trying to sell an overpriced treatment. Just crank the heat up to the high 80's to low 90's and keep the water well oxygenated with an airstone if you don't have one running. No need to medicate, the ich will be taken care of in roughly 3 - 4 weeks using this method. If the other tank isn't cycled, you'll likely kill the fish trying to treat them in it since the tank will be cycling while they're already weakened from the ich. Very bad combination.

Comment: @Jestep consider making your comment an answer.

Comment: @Jestep, while I appreciate the concern regarding medication, my fish got better fast and all survived, they were back to normal within a week. One of the fish was (is) a Julii Cory and they absolutely do *not* enjoy low 90s or even high 80s really. I did end up moving them and they did fine in the empty tank. I kept the temperature around 84C and just had the filter (without carbon) running. It was easier to do partial water changes and keeping it warm. Honestly, when I pay $4 a fish, to pay $4 for 2 treatments worth of tablets isn't that big of a deal to be. It seems to have worked.

Comment: @Catsunami It's interesting that the cory's were having trouble with the temperature. I've kept them in very warm discus tanks before that were kept in the high 80's to low 90's basically permanently, without any issue, actually had them try and spawn as well. As far as cost, it definitely depends on the treatment. I routinely see people buying expensive bottles of rid ich and other much more expensive methods than what you used. Since freshwater ich does have a distinct lifecycle, keep a close eye out in case it was in an untreatable dormant form, but glad to hear you have it under control.